# Django REST Framework: Two models nested via a third one (with 2 FKs )

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I have two main models in my Django project:

```
class User(Model):  # let's say this is the built-in User model
    ...

class Thing(Model):
    ...
```

and I have a helper model defining their relationship:

```
class ThingUsage(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='thing_usages')
    thing = ForeignKey(Thing, related_name='thing_usages')
    role = CharField()
```

What would be the best way to set up DRF routing so that I could refer to `Thing`s like this:

```
'/users/{user_pk}/things/'  # for listing
'/users/{user_pk}/things/{thing_pk}'  # for a specific Thing
```

(which should access all `Thing`s that are related to the `User` via a `ThingUsage`).

I am guessing that writing my own Router/ViewSet (or whatever else is needed) wouldn't be hard, but I'm wondering if there is a ready-to-use solution (seeing the huge amounts of available DRF extensions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `nested routes` from [drf-extensions](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes), try this:

```
#inside urls.py
router = ExtendedSimpleRouter()
(
    router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
          .register(r'things', ThingViewSet, parents_query_lookups=['thing_usages__user'])
)

#inside views.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()


class ThingViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Thing.objects.all()
```

Comment: I actually have thought of doing it this way, but discarderd the idea for some silly reason.... But it works! Thanks! (btw: had to use `thing_usages__user__username`)

Comment: Yep, i didn't notice you have `related_name='thing_usages'`, but `__username`? Do you have `lookup_field = 'username'` inside your `UserViewSet`?

Comment: Yeah, I my UserViewSet is a bit different. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: No problem, the important thing is that you managed it to make it work :)

Comment: add a manytomany on either User or Thing with your through table set to your ThingUsage and django will fix up the direct relations for you so you dont have to go via usages and can go directly user.things and thing.users